# How to precisely test if CSS final computed values have changed anywhere on a page?

Tags: css, class, browser, output

I have a situation where I need to merge several classes manually.  They contain a huge amount of overrides within an 18,000 line CSS file.

I started making some changes to the huge CSS file and I realize that CSS loads the last case of a property so I did this all very carefully.  For the most part things worked well.  But, I did find one icon that was wrong and one text link that was the wrong font.  So I thought, is there a way that I can compare the before and after state of this work precisely.  I don't mean visually.  But instead like two full text output files of the results of the computed CSS for the entire current page so I can run a compare on them in notepad++

Sorry if this is an ignorant question as I am a self taught web novice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use notepad ++ to compare two files. You will need a compare plugin to be installed in notepad ++. Please follow the steps below:

**Install the Compare Plugin**
1. Launch Notepad++.

2. Click the “Plugins” menu, select “Plugin Manager” and click “Show Plugin Manager.” A list of currently available plugins populates the plugin manager screen.
3. Check the box next to “Compare.”
4. Click the “Install” button at the bottom of the screen. The Compare plugin will download and install. If an administrator authentication dialog appears, click the “Allow” button.

**Using the Notepad++ Compare Plugin**
1. Launch Notepad++ and open the two files you wish to run a comparison check on.

2. Click the “Plugins” menu, select “Compare” and click “Compare.” The plugin will run a comparison check and display the two files side by side, with any differences in the text highlighted.
3. Reset to the original window configuration and appearance by clicking the “Plugins” menu, selecting “Compare” and clicking “Clear Results.”

For reference click [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-diff-notepad-44587.html)

Comment: Thanks,  I am familiar with doing compares like that in Notepad++.  The question, I should maybe have been clearer is about what files I am comparing.   I need the final computed version of each class.  Some classes in the stylesheet are repeated 6 times.  I know I can see "computed" for one element.  But is there a way to see the entire result of the computed page in text?

Comment: please have a look on this https://github.com/bertjohnson/CSSCompare If it could help

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  I am surprised that there is not an addon for Firefox or Chrome to export all loaded final "computed" styles into a text document.  This is mostly needed because we have some properties with even 10 overrides!  I will have to see if CSSCompare considers that.  As we merge these overrides we simply want to know if anything changed in the way FF or Chrome is outputting the result.

Comment: I am now trying the "single file" addon for chrome since it can make a single text file result with CSS baked in.  If I do a compare before and after, I think I will find changes to the page.